# Не отображается favicon

Tags: html, yii

Как и советуют, в лэйаут\мейн прописал

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Закинул в папку иконку.

Но ничего не увидел. Как можно в css где-то еще посмотреть, что проиходит?

В исходном коде вижу

```
 <link type="image/x-icon" href="/yiiproj/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
```

Имею - картинка появилась только в хроме. В фф и ие её нет. Возможно, проблема в том, что я на локальном сервере (опенсервер)?

Comment: - А зачем нужен  favicon?
- А где его смотрят?
- А в кеш он попадает вместе с другим контентом?
- А если его нет в указанном пути?

ПС: И зачем Вы усложняете, залейте файлик в рутовую директорию веба, кому надо тот сам его там найдет.

Comment: неа, из рута тож не работает

Comment: Обновите через Ctrl+F5

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать так.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: неа, так тож не хочет

Comment: ты говоришь, у тебя путь показывает вот такой /yiiproj/images/favicon.ico вбей в адресную строку, он ее вообще находит?